# Custom Build Summary entries in TFS Team Build

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have succesfully added a custom build step to my TFS Team Build script, however, after my build fails (as intended by my custom build step), I want to add a URL to my custom failure report in the "Summary" section at the top of the build report.
This is the section that says...
"Build Name:"
"Requested by:"
"Team project:"
etc

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with the current versions of Team Foundation Server.  The only thing that you could possibly customize in TFS2008 is to change the Build Log location to point to a URL that contains the information you are interested in along with a link to the actual build log should somebody want to look at the full details.

For more information on updating the log location, take a look at the following blog post of mine:

http://www.woodwardweb.com/teamprise/000415.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if this cannot be done.  See the first part of this post for confirmation.

http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/archive/2008/12/22/update-in-using-stylecop-in-tfs-team-build.aspx

You can add it to IBuildInformation to access programmatically (if say, you had a custom dashboard to show your build status).

Vaccano